# AngularJs - Getting the immediate value from an input area

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So here is the area to let users to change the value.

```
 <div flex="15" align="right">
     <label class="title-label required">Value</label>
 </div>
 <md-input-container class="md-block hide-error-space" flex="25">
     <input name="value" ng-model="ProductCtrl.ProductInfoSingle.sortOrder"
            ng-disabled="false">
 </md-input-container>
```

and here is the button to trigger the function.

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-accent"
           ng-click="ProductCtrl.ProductInfo(ProductCtrl.ProductInfo)">
  update
</md-button>
```

So I would like to print the value in console when I clicked the button as below.

```
vm.ProductInfo = function (project, e) {   
    console.log(vm.sortOrder);
}
```

However I can only get the defaulted value; the printed values remain the same (the defaulted value) when I change the value in the input.

How can I get the correct value?

Comment: Have you defined/initialized ProductInfoSingle with the property of sortOrder in the controller?

Comment: `ngmodel` should be `ng-model`.  You are passing the click handler to itself `onclick`.  And you can't define the input model using the name of the controller like that unless it's an alias.

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('angularExampleModule',[])
        .controller('angularExampleController', ['$scope', angularExampleController]);

    function angularExampleController($scope){
      $scope.productInfoSingle = {
        sortOrder: 'default'
      };
      $scope.productInfo = function (project, e) {
       console.log($scope.productInfoSingle.sortOrder);
      }
}
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h4>"Check Console output"</h4>
<div ng-app="angularExampleModule" ng-controller="angularExampleController">
<div flex="15" align="right">
 </div>
 <md-input-container class="md-block hide-error-space" flex="25">
 <input name="value" ng-model="productInfoSingle.sortOrder" ng-disabled="false">
 </md-input-container>
 
 <button class="md-raised md-accent" ng-click="productInfo()">update</button>
 </div>
```

OR check this : https://codepen.io/DeepaliK/pen/KGrOXG?editors=1010#0